# Función que ejecute un submit y luego otro submit en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

quisiera saber como puedo crear una función que ejecute un `submit` si otro `submit` ya se ejecuto, lo pregunto por que tengo 2 formularios los cuales deseo enviar con un solo botón pero la siguiente función no me sirve por que no me valida los formularios que fue la que ya use:

```
function enviar() {
    document.form.action = "example.php";
    document.form.target = "_blank";
    document.form.submit(); 

    return true;
}
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Para eso, el primer `submit` debe ser por AJAX y, luego de obtener la respuesta del servidor, disparar el `submit` del segundo form.

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por tu respuesta, no puedo hacerlo por ajax por que el servidor no me acepta las peticiones y hace bloqueo del CORS.

Comment: Yo lo que haría es administrar el envío de ambos formularios desde la misma función. Dentro de la función, validas el primer form, si todo es correcto validas el segundo form y si todo sigue siendo correcto lanzas el contenido de los dos form al servidor, procesando los datos allí y haciendo los inserts o lo que necesites hacer con esos datos. Eso en caso de que los datos de un form no dependan del otro.

Answer (score 2):

Si estás utilizando JavaScript, creo que la mejor opción es utilizar las promesas para hacer este tipo de operativa.

```
let promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
// do a thing, possibly async, then…
if (primerSubmit()) {
    resolve("Se ha hecho el primer submit");
} else {
    reject(Error("No se ha ejecutado el primer submit"));
}
});

promise.then(
(result) => {
    alert(result); // "Se ha hecho el primer submit!"
    segundoSubmit();
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
});

function primerSubmit() {
//logica de envio del primer formulario
return true;
}

function segundoSubmit() {
alert('Se ha enviado el segundo formulario')
}
```

De manera muy resumida:

- He creado dos funciones, cada una de ellas hace el submit que le
  corresponda.
- He creado una variable y le he dado por valor una nueva instancia de
  promesa JavaScript que llama a la función del primer submit.
- He invocado a la variable de la promesa y, mediante el operador
  .then(), espero a que resuelva el primer submit y después lanzo la
  función del segundo submit (incluye un time out para darle un aspecto
  más real a la espera de la resolución de la promesa).

Creo que además podría serte de ayuda el siguiente enlace con información sobre qué son y como se utilizan las promesas en JavaScript:

- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises?hl=es

Por último, aquí está un enlace a Plunker en el que se ve en funcionamiento este código que comenté arriba:

- https://plnkr.co/edit/ZMyUhohpVg9bskKftxzu?p=info

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por tu respuesta, esto funcionaria igual con un solo boton?

Comment: Hola, está hecho para funcionar con un único botón. Lo que tendrás que hacer es que el botón ejecute una función ejecutando la promesa (la parte del promise.then()...

Comment: El segundo formulario **jamás** se ejecutará. En cuanto hagas el submit del primer formulario, se ejecutará la promesa, pero en cuanto salga del `alert`, se hará la petición hacia el servidor y el documento volverá a cargarse.

Comment: @gugadev en caso de que cuando envíe el formulario recargue la página, lo que necesitará es guardar la confirmación de que se ha enviado en, por ejemplo, el SessionStorage, y cuando se rellene la variable que un evento lance el segundo submit.

Comment: Sí, y en conjunto con un query param que indique que el segundo formulario debe dispararse. La promesa no es necesaria en el caso del OP porque no funciona.

1. Enviar primer form.
2. Server recibe, renderiza y añade un query param: `?submit=2`
3. Debe haber un script que verifique si existe ese parámetro, en ese caso, toma la info del session o local storage, rellena y hace el submitl

Answer (score 1):

estoy de acuerdo con el uso de promesas pero también puedes condicionar tu función "enviar" con apoyo de una variable global

```
var formulario = 1

function enviar() {
   if(formulario === 1){
      document.form.action = "example.php";
      document.form.target = "_blank";
      document.form.submit(); 
      formulario++
      return true;
   }else{
      //aquí ejecutas el segundo bloque de código
      //después de esto puedes devolver la variable formulario a 1 con "formulario--"
      //o talvez necesites volver a incrementar y agregar otra condición para un tercer formulario
    }
}
```

Te dejo otro ejemplo de usar un mismo botón con la misma función condicionando de la misma manera, igual y te sirve de guía.

```
const btnEnviar = document.getElementById('btn')

//La variable "formulario" debe tener un scope global para que funcione
var formulario = 1

btnEnviar.addEventListener('click', enviarFormulario)

function enviarFormulario() {
    if (formulario === 1) {
        //aqui se ejecuta lo del primer formulario
        alert('Formulario 1')
        //para usar el mismo boton se incrementa la variable global que se usa como condición
        formulario++
    }else{
        //aqui se ejecuta lo del segundo formulario
        alert('Formulario 2')
        //despues de esto puedes devolver la variable formulario a 1 con "formulario--"
        //o talvez necesites volver a incrementar y agregar otra condicion para un tercer formulario
    }
}
```